# How to drop class and all associated indexes in OrientDB?

Tags: sql, orientdb

Is there any way to drop all indexes when dropping a class, that is, can I replace the following 2 statements with just one:

```
DROP CLASS Plan           IF EXISTS;
DROP INDEX Plan.id        IF EXISTS;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, it will force deleting your class : `DROP CLASS Plan UNSAFE`